# diaplay pdf in an aspx page using an iframe

Tags: asp.net, iframe

Right now, I am displaying my pdf using iframe. this opens the pdf reader present in the system to display the pdf.
I want to display the pdf in an aspx page instead. But using iframe. It should open a pop-up, but the pop-up should be a aspx page with a close button

I have tried using this code, But this displays the code in the same ie page. I want the aspx page to be a popup with just a close button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilePath = Server.MapPath("sample.pdf");
    WebClient User = new WebClient();
    Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
    if (FileBuffer != null)
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is telling the ASPX page to deliver a PDF download, not an ASPX-page consisting of HTML and things.

Comment: Yeah, basically it gets displayed in the browser in the same page. can you tell me how to have it in a iframe model popup ?

Comment: can i have a aspx page popped up in an iframe popup ?